# Removing the default print button functionality in Print Preview Dialog

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using Winforms and I created a print preview dialog in order to print a report. I also created my own Print functionality on a different button of the print preview. On the print preview dialog there is also a print button. I want to create a new handler on that button in order for my own method to be called.

I managed to add a handler to my method by using

```
 ((ToolStripButton)((ToolStrip)dlgPreview.Controls[1]).Items[0]).Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
```

Using this though both methods are called. Given that I only use `+=` . It creates a new handler and attaches it to the button. Both handlers are called. I suppose I could remove the original handler by using `-=` but what would I put on the right side of `-=`?

Is there another way to remove the original handler and only have my personal one?
I am using `C#` and `Winforms`

Comment: Just hope _they_ won't ever ever ever change anything in that window or your code will be broken. Can't you use `PrintPreviewControl` around a new form instead of such _hacking_ on `PrintPreviewDialog`? BTW if you want to suffer and you don't want to change...well you may use Reflection to clear backing store delegate for that event.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti An idea came to my mind on how to fix this issue and I did, and it solved my problem after I posted the question so I also posted the answer to my problem below

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti what do you mean change anything in my window?

Comment: If, for any reason on earth, they add another button on that window (before the print one). You're working with _indices_ and they'll be broken. Also toolbar with index 1? It's an implementation detail, what if they move it? Also searching for name (much better than indices, btw): what if they change it? You're relying on **implementation details** (so small that even winforms guys don't worry about them). Yes code on framework is more stable and winforms probably is abandoned (then it won't change) but...are you SURE? It's really too fragile, especially because there are better alternatives.

Comment: Moreover think you removed a button...did you try in every condition? Are you sure it works in every configuration? What if there isn't an installed printer (just for example)?

Comment: And...finally...why on earth you have to replace the print button to do printing??? Isn't what `PrintDocument` events are for???

Comment: I have created my own personal printing handler that does more things than the default one. And when that specific button is clicked calls the default one. I have extra functionality needed. And as stated before and in many other occasions Winforms is "dead" so Microsoft will not perform any changes on how it works. Now if they decide to remove completely then I will change everything. But in my country all business work with winforms. None of them have invested the time and money to develop in WPF or any other form of development other than that. Just like with Windows XP. Too far left behind

Comment: "extra functionality" can be added with subclassing. Let me explain what I mean: when you click "print" then `PrintPreviewDialog` simply demand to `PrintDocument.Print()`. It does nothing more than demanding to `PrintController` where logic is. `PrintController` can be subclassed too but it also notify `PrintDocument` calling `OnBeginPrint()`. That's your entry point, you can subclass `PrintDocument` to override `OnBeginPrint()` or add an event handler for `BeginPrint`...no need to replace UI button to do something before printing begins.

Comment: It's a stable technology but it doesn't mean it won't change (especially because it'll be supported for a long time). If a new Windows version will add/change something they can't ignore, if a severe security bug arises...they will change it (for sure they won't worry to keep control index stable!) and your code will be broken. It may even be broken in some circumstances but not always (because of local patches).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it to work by removing the specific button that was there, create a new button with my own functionality and adding it there.

Using this code

```
     ToolStripButton b = new ToolStripButton();
 b.ImageIndex = ((ToolStripButton)((ToolStrip)dlgPreview.Controls[1]).Items[0]).ImageIndex;

        ((ToolStrip)dlgPreview.Controls[1]).Items.Remove(((ToolStripButton)((ToolStrip)dlgPreview.Controls[1]).Items[0]));
        b.Visible = true;
        ((ToolStrip)dlgPreview.Controls[1]).Items.Insert(0, b);
        ((ToolStripButton)((ToolStrip)dlgPreview.Controls[1]).Items[0]).Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
```

Basically I am:

1. Creating a new button
2. Getting the image from the original button
3. Remove the original button from the toolstrip
4. Add the new button
5. Add my personal handler

Comment: Just a word of warning, as previously mentioned this is likely to cause pain later on down the line should they change the code that you are relying on to perform his hack. I would seriously reconsider.

Comment: @BenjaminPaul please elaborate more. Changing the code of Winforms you mean?

Comment: Yes, he means to the form code itself.  Highly unlikely, though.

Comment: @DonBoitnott unlikely (just because WinForms is a _dead_ technology) but not impossible (and terribly hard to debug unless you inspect WinForms code to see what may happen). Did you ever worry to move a control because it'll change its index in the control collection? Of course not. Moreover the point is not _just_ this but that problem itself is weird: to replace print button to do...what? We have `PrintDocument` for that...kind of XY problem, IMO.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti My point exactly. Winforms is considered "dead" and not changes come to it. Now if Microsoft ever decides to remove it completely from .net framework then it will really be an issue. But no changes will ever happen to the future